# How to make payment to store business account byu paypal?

Tags: mobile, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am developing an mobile app where I present products (items) from different stores just like ebay.com. User can select product, can add to cart and then finally can make payment via paypal.

I have created an Paypal business account on sandbox. Currently all payment made by users are coming to this business account I mentioned in my code. But my requirement is different. I want that payment should go to store's (product owner's) account.

So I made changes so that whenever i make call to paypal I chnaged business account email to store owner email address and payment done successfully. :) Payment posted to store owner business.

I made changes only in paypal.recipient email address but still paypal object is created by my paypal application ID. This is what I am worried about. Does it will work on production mode? I really doubt that.

Please help me guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

What API or service are you using to do this?  Are you just using Website Payments Standard, Exprses Checkout, or one of the other API?  You mentiioned application id, are you using Adaptive Payments?  You could use Adative Payments to do what you are wanting to, if you are not already doing this.  This would allow you to process payments and split it between different accounts.  In your business model, it would allow you to split the payments between different store owners if the buyers checkout contained items from different merchants/stores.